# How to execute shell script within a docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I have a docker container that, at start up, executes a shell script (startService.sh), which uses the "source" linux keyword (which my docker container doesn't like).  I'm seeing the error message below when running my image:

./startService.sh: 6: ./startService.sh: source: not found

Why am I seeing this error? Can one not use the "source" linux command in a script in an image?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

    

    VOLUME /opt/att/ajsc/config

    COPY startService.sh /startService.sh

    RUN chmod 777 /startService.sh

    ENTRYPOINT ./startService.sh
```

startService.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

    export AJSC_HOME=/opt/att/ajsc

    export AJSC_CONFIG_HOME=${AJSC_HOME}/config

    

    source /opt/att/ajsc/etc/config /run.source
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is a command present in `bash`, but not in `sh`. In `sh`, use single dot `.`. 
The single dot `.` works in `bash`, too.

Your script has shebang `#!/bin/sh`. Either replace `source` with `.`, or replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash`.

(This issue has nothing to do with docker.)